# How to fix: Could not resolve `.../record-mapper.registry` from `.../record.store.factory.js`?

Tags: angular

When trying to build an angular application `ng build core --configuration production` I get the following message:

```
$ suitecrm-8.local git:(feature/extension-module) ✗ yarn run build:core
yarn run v1.22.19
$ ng build core --configuration production
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'core'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ Compiling with Angular in legacy View Engine compilation mode.
✖ Bundling to FESM2015
Could not resolve '../../../../../../../dist/common/lib/record/record-mappers/record-mapper.registry' from dist/core/esm2015/lib/store/record/record.store.factory.js
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This command fails in the `Bundling to FESM2015` step. I have identified that `record.store.factory.js` imports `record-mapper.registry` from the wrong location but also in the path `dist/common/lib/record/record-mappers/` there are only type definitions like `record-mapper.registry.d.ts`

Could you give me some hint on how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have similar issue with persistence package & i have correct the path which is incorrect that solve my issue

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in my case correcting the path seems not to be enough. Even correcting the path, the file you are trying to locate `record-mapper.registry` does not exist in that location. Although if `record-mapper.registry.d.ts`

Comment: Also, when running the `ng build core --configuration production` command the `dist/core/esm2015/lib/store/record/record.store.factory.js` file is rebuilt so the modified path is lost

Comment: may i know for what purpose this "store" or "record" is used in side "lib" folder? it's some third party package or your own ?

Comment: which SuiteCRM 8.* version are you referring to exactly, please?

Comment: @ParthM.Dave this is from the SuiteCRM 8 architecture which is a third party Opensource CRM.